# Some Parse methods not working in iOS SDK

Tags: ios7, xcode5, parse-platform

I added the Parse SDK today (1.2.15) to an existing project which targets iOS7 and is built in Xcode5. I followed the instructions on https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#ios/native/existing exactly. Some things work, like creating and saving a PFObject. Certain functions however cannot be found by the compiler. For instance `[PFUser enableAutomaticUser];` generates the error

> AppDelegate.m:21:13: No known class method for selector 'enableAutomaticUser'

and `[PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];` generates the error

> AppDelegate.m:20:6: Use of undeclared identifier 'PFAnalytics'

Are the docs out of date and have these methods moved? I have tried restarting Xcode and cleaning my project. I can see the PFAnalytics.h file if I expand Parse.Framework in Xcode, and when I look at PFUser.h I can see a declaration of `enableAutomaticUser;`. Why can Xcode see some Parse classes and methods but not others?

Comment: can you try to remove your project derived data because clean project in some cases is not enough. Delete them in Window->Organizer->Projects->YourProject, restart the xcode, open project, rebuild it. Finger cross that it would work

Comment: I solved it and posted my solution, but this is also good advice that has solved similar problems for some. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that `Framework Search Paths` in **Build Settings** contained two directories, and one was invalid, resulting in this very strange behavior where some methods in Parse worked and others didn't.